# Yii2 equivalent code to Yii1

Tags: import, yii2

I'm having a problem and I can't find a good answer to it, I have this in a Yii1 extension code:

```
Yii::import("ext.EAjaxUpload.qqFileUploader");
```

I need the equivalent code in Yii2, I read about create a class, but It was not good explained!

Please help and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you added extension through composer then you don't need to import class. For using the extension you just need to use http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: No, I extracted the extension and place it into the extensions folder! But, I have that problem, I'm going to try to add the extension through Composer!

Comment: BTW, that documentation is for Yii2 too? Because, as I know, Yii is a modificated version of PHP!

Comment: of course it is for yii2 too. Yii is not a modification of php. It is a framework made on php.